# Graph API - adding a user in another Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is there a way of adding a user in another Microsoft Azure Active Directory from Graph API, as I do from the Azure Portal?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you trying to add a regular user in a directory while signed in as a user from another directory (e.g. bob@contoso.onmicrosoft.com, trying to add alice@fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com into fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com), or are you trying to add an external user to the directory the signed in user is a member of (bob@contoso.onmicrosoft.com, trying to add alice@fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com into contoso.onmicrosoft.com)?

Comment: Hi Philippe, I'm trying to perform the same operation that I can perform from the Azure Portal. Let's say I have 2 AD  : A and B, I would like to add a user@A.com on  B's AD. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding external users from another directory via Graph API is not currently supported.

Comment: Thanks! That's the answer I was looking for.